# Passing props between siblings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to share props from components to sibling children. I've read about React Context but can't implement it.

My home component looks like this:

```
const Home = () => {
    return ( 
        <>
            <Navigation />
            <SearchBar />
            <Wrapper>
                <Filters />
                <ProductsList />
            </Wrapper>
        </>
     );
}
```

I have search state in SearchBar component, and need to pass it to ProductList component

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

const handleSetSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
}

return ( 
    <Wrapper>
        <StyledTitle>inPal Search</StyledTitle>
        <InputWrapper>
            <StyledInput type="text" placeholder="Write something..." onChange={(e) => handleSetSearch(e)} />
            <SearchIcon src={searchIcon} alt="Search" />
        </InputWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
 );
```

Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: You will likely need to lift the state up, and then pass down the state and update functions to all the children who need it.

Comment: You can lift `setSearch` with both `search`, I assume, in `Home` component. Pass `setSearch` as a prop to `SearchBar` and the `search` state to `ProductsList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the state in parent component (`Home`) and pass it as prop to both the child components as:

```
const Home = () => {

const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

return ( 
    <>
        <Navigation />
        <SearchBar search={search} setSearch={setSearch} />
        <Wrapper>
            <Filters />
            <ProductsList search={search} />
        </Wrapper>
    </>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import ProductsList from "./ProductsList";


const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

const handleSetSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
}
const Sr = createContext();


return ( 
    <Wrapper>
        <StyledTitle>inPal Search</StyledTitle>
        <InputWrapper>
            <StyledInput type="text" placeholder="Write something..." onChange={(e) => handleSetSearch(e)} />
            <SearchIcon src={searchIcon} alt="Search" />
        </InputWrapper>
<Sr.Provider value={search}>   
<ProductsList/>
</Sr.Provider>
 </Wrapper>
 );

ProductList
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Sr } from "./App";
const ProductList = () => {
    const sr = useContext(Sr);
    return <h1> your value is here {sr} </h1>
}
```